# DataGridView changing the row selected doesn't fire cell click event

Tags: c#, datagridview

C# Winforms

When changing the selection, it doesn't trigger click event.

```
private void ChangeSelection(rowIndex){
    dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;    
}
```

I can call it like calling a normal function as below.

```
dataGridView_Click(new object(), new System.EventArgs());

Designer.cs:
this.dataGridView.Click += new System.EventHandler(dataGridView_Click);
```

Important note here is this click event is in sink with Native C++ Classes.

[Sink Windows Forms Events from Native C++ Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af8w7d7d.aspx)

My problem is when I call like a normal function, it is not getting hit in native app.
I need to trigger this click programatically as like it is being clicked by the user with a mouse.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please confirm: Do you want to click on a cell, a row or the datagridview itself?

Comment: I want the Click on a row!?

Comment: but look like datagridview doesn't have any RowClick event, we just have CellClick, CellContentClick

Comment: Ok fine. It's ok for me if I can atleast get the datagridview click event.

Comment: I think you want to raise some Click event on your datagridview by OnClick, not on any cell, the method you posted `dataGridView_Click` shows me that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41710/discussion-between-akn-and-king-king)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `Reflection` to raise the `Click` event via `OnClick` because this raising method is protected:

```
typeof(Control).GetMethod("OnClick", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
               .Invoke(dataGridView1, new object[]{EventArgs.Empty});
```

The `BindingFlags` has full type name `System.Reflection.BindingFlags`

Answer (score 0):

You can also call cell click event for selection changed event

```
private void dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     DataGridView dv = (DataGridView)sender;
     dgv_CellClick(dv, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(dv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dv.CurrentCell.RowIndex));}
```

private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){ // Do your stuff hear!    }